# Hi. I am very new to flutter. Flutter Demo error

Tags: flutter

I am very new to flutter. I just installed it today and no issues in my installation. but when I run flutter Demo it came out with errors. As its a demo project I understand there is some installation or updation problem, plz find the images . can anyone help me with this, please

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxwlf.gif)

Comment: For people to help you, you should paste the actual code and the output from the debug log into your question rather than a screenshot. This helps others search the code and ultimately find a solution.

Comment: sorry I am very new to the community.. will do

Comment: This was the default demo flutter project ..

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate your app to Android X in the toolbar:

Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX and follow the prompts. See if that fixes the error.

Comment: @DJ11 can you please run: ' flutter doctor ' in the terminal and add that output to your question

Answer (score 0):

You just have to migrate to AndroidX..

Follow this:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration